# does exist some manner could fast insert code in confluence?

Tags: markdown, confluence

My company uses confluence wiki, and some documents and share record here. But I found it's not very convenient, e.g. insert some code block , I have to type `ctrl+shift+a` then choose code block then choose language(e.g. bash java and so on) , if uses markdown just ```` ``` code here ``` ````.

does exist some manner could fast insert code in confluence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start typing

```
{cod
```

then `return` and paste your code.
I think it's faster

Comment: thank you very much! and does confluence could use ` highlight part `

Answer (score 0):

For Confluence 5 I now use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then paste in the code, then manually add `{code}` tags at the top and bottom.

This is mostly due to that [pasting in text straight into the code macro in the editor can strip or stuff up the code formatting](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/11/why-we-removed-wiki-markup-editor-in-confluence-4/).